# Looking for ionic app that works on offfline mode (i.e. without internet)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 (angularjs) app, which doesn't work offline, on first launch user creates account, logs in and next time he opens app he is already logged in.

The scenario is I am looking for is an offline mode(that is without internet connection), here if the user is not connected to internet he's not allowed to explore the app, here i want to let the user explore the app even without internet connection, with the credentials already logged in.

A lot of resources suggests to use localstorage, but i can't find any relevant resources regarding the same.

I have spent hour reading and testing different approaches but well even more confused than ever. It seems to me as such important feature of hybrid app that there should be a good implementation... Would appreciate any help/suggestions/examples/links...

My ultimate goal would be that once authorized user can access and manipulate his profile data even if in offline mode. That means that opening app allready logs him in an his profile info is stored as well.

My minimum viable goal would be that when app is opened app recognizes user, checks as logged in, redirects to logged in state and makes http to get all user details. While user is waiting for that response there are loading spinners but he can start to use logged in app experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection windows is controlling your App. So basing on this, you can easily make a checknetwork function to make it check if you want.

If this function return "false" then you bypass the login if only the user has already logged in.
On your provider for the LogPage, you should control this kind of things with shared values as

```
let isOnceConnected: boolean;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

bro just store your token generated by the server or user data in local storage, If the user is in the local storage then redirect the page other send it to the login page,

local storage like

to set =>

```
localStorage.setItem('auth-token', JSON.stringify(access_token));
```

to get =>

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth-token'));
```

Also, you can use [Storage plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage) to store any data.